# How can I control fps of my camera changed?

Tags: python, opencv, camera

I purchased a camera of the link :
https://ko.aliexpress.com/item/32991611812.html?spm=a2g0o.order_detail.order_detail_item.4.29fe5ccdun4DWn&gatewayAdapt=glo2kor

I bought this because it can capture video with fps of 60 or 120, when setting the resolution of capture size.

I am now using openCV/python and made a code to control my camera.

```
        self.vs = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
        self.expo = self.vs.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_EXPOSURE)
        print('expose:',self.expo)
        self.vs.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640)
        self.vs.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 480)
        self.vs.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, 60)
```

The frame size and exposure control works well, but fps is fixed to 30 and does not change no matter what I do.

I found several code to control FPS, which is for FPS value smaller than 30.

Can you tell me how to control the camera properly ?

Comment: set FOURCC property to `VideoWriter_forucc(*"MJPG")`. play with the order of set() calls.